# Matrix multiplication via iterators help needed

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, overloading, operator-keyword

So Im trying to implement an operator overload which will allows me to multiply a matrix and a vector. The matrix is itself a vector of vectors. I have produced code which achieves this through use of for-loops and simple vector indexing, however, I'd like to try implement it with iterators.

My first step was to produce an operator overload which allows me to 'multiply' vectors. In this sense multiplying is a row by row operations. So for two vectors a = {a1,a2,a3} and b = {b1,b2,b3}, the results of a*b is {a1b1, a2b2, a3b3}. This was implemented as follows:

```
template<typename T> 
vector<double> operator*(const vector<T> &v1, const vector<T> &v2) //vector * vector [broken down matrix] Not dot product
{
    vector<double> output(v2.size());
    int pos = 0;            

    for(auto &row : v1){
        for(auto &col : v2){
            output[pos] = col*row;  
        }
        pos++;
    }
    return output; 
}
```

My idea was to then implement pretty much the following code for the multiplication of a matrix * vector:

```
template<typename T> 
vector<double> operator*(const vector<vector<T> > &v1, const vector<T> &v2) //matrix * vector 
{
    vector<double> output(v2.size()); 
    int pos = 0; 

    for(auto &row : v1){
            output[pos] = row*v2; 
        }
        pos++; 
    return output; 
}
```

I think I know my problem. row is not a vector, so when I try to do row*v2, it does not make sense, nor does it used the vector * vector operator overload. So my question is, how can I make it so that the iterator operates over a vector of vectors, allowing the desired multiplication properties. Perhaps this approach is fundamentally floored, in which case I welcome any additional help. Thanks

follow up question: As seen, these are template functions. Is there a way  I can declare the vector 'output' in terms of the typename T. I.e so that when integer vectors/matrices are passed into the function, integer vectors are returned, and when double vectors/matrices are passed into the function, double vectors are returned.

Comment: range based for loops are best when the order is not essential, iterator based loops are best when the index does not matter. When you need the index, there is nothing wrong about using a loop index. Why do you want to use iterators?

Comment: Please ask one question per question. If you have more you can ask several seperate questions.

Comment: Are you just doing this for learning purposes? A vector of vectors is a particularly inefficient way to represent a matrix.

Comment: Your first function is returning `{a1b3, a2b3, a3b3}`. How do you multiply a matrix times a vector on paper? Write out a simple 3x3 matrix times a 3x1 vector and see what the operations is.

Comment: Your question, while looking well-presented on the surface, suffers from a lack of coherent substance. *(Your first function does not do what you claim it does, you refer to "the iterator" when there is not an iterator, you claim to know your problem but do not describe the symptoms, etc.)* My impression is that you are having trouble identifying a concrete question because you don't have a clear idea of what you want to ask. Maybe you need to take more time to figure out how you intend your approach to work and where it is going wrong? Focus on a single piece and maybe simplify your example?

Comment: @JaMiT Yes sorry, I think you are correct. Going into this I thought that in the first function I listed, the iterators were 'row' and 'col' and they were iterating over the containers v1 and v2. I suppose that is not so, and I'll look into it more - it was kinda just something  I thought I'd experiment with. I'm not necessarily asking for a solution here, but do you think this problem could implement matrix * vector multiplication with iterators, such that its more efficient than a for-loop implementation?

Comment: @John Yes, a mistake indeed, one of many in fact! back to the drawing board

Comment: @doug I was specifically using vectors in this task to try learn more about them (using it to solve triangular matrices) - but I would welcome suggestions for more efficient ways of representing matrices, Other than perhaps a 2d array.

Comment: Take a look at `std::valarray` which is designed for matrix work. Specifically it is supposed to restrict aliasing to improve C++ performance with matrixes. They don't use iterators but rather something called a `slice` to divvy up rows and columns. However, most people have migrated towards using `std::vector` in a class with  the `operator()` defined to access rows and columns.

Comment: @jonah765 The terminology might be one point of confusion here. In C++, an "[iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator)" is analogous to a pointer. When using a traditional `for` loop to go through a container, you likely would name an iterator. However, a range-based `for` loop skips naming the iterator, instead naming the elements to which the iterator (from the traditional loop) would point. In your case, `row` and `col` are not iterators, assuming standard C++ terminology. (They are elements, or more precisely, aliases for elements.)